# округление в JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

Получаю я по аяксу строку. Строка - это сума денег на счете, но её присылают в формате 9.7500 - это 9 грн. 75 коп. Как бы мне убрать последние два нолика, что бы получить 9.75 грн.?

```
   $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'functions.php',
      data: msg,
      success: function(data) {
          $('#message').html(data); 
      },
      error: function(xhr, str){
        alert('Виникла помилка: ' + xhr.responseCode);
      }
    });
```

Comment: а как из `10.0000` убрав `00` можно получить `9.75`?

Comment: ну это например

Comment: всегда приходят 4 знака после запятой? и последние 2 всегда `00`?

Comment: спасибо, я просто запутался, потому что получаю не только 9.7500, а еще и html теги, потому NaN.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Тут возможно несколько вариантов.

1. Если есть доступ к серверной части, то делать это там.
2. Если от сервера приходит гарантированых 4 знака после запятой, то отрезать их строковыми функциями js: **slice()** или **substr()** (есть ограничения в ИЕ).
3. Если от сервера приходит строковое представление гарантированно вещественного числа, то можно преобразовать его с помощью **parseFloat()**, а потом округлить его с помощью **Math.round()** до нужного формата.

Comment: спасибо, я просто запутался, потому что получаю не только 9.7500, а еще и html теги, потому NaN. Да это все работает. Я округляю еще на сервере PHP = echo round($text, 2)." грн.";

Answer (score 2):

Два знака после запятой

```js
alert( 10.0000.toFixed(2) )
```

Comment: приходит строка

Comment: спасибо, я просто запутался, потому что получаю не только 9.7500, а еще и html теги, потому NaN. Да это все работает. Я округляю еще на сервере PHP = echo round($text, 2)." грн.";